# Search the row that content a different style with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a list inside a table and I want to get index of the row that the style is different.

[screenshot](http://puu.sh/jPqO9/1567745ad6.png)

Comment: it would be easier if you post your code

Comment: You need to iterate through each row in your table and find which tr node has that class. 
Like this : 

$("#tableID tr").each(function(index,options){ 
        if($(this).attr("class") == "classToFind")
         alert('Class found at index : ' + index );  
});

Next time please post your code so that people can get aware of the issue.